# How many different "Dwayne" "The Rock" "Johnson" orderings can be made for $n$ Dwayne The Rock Johnsons?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, puzzle

Let me explain. Whenever I hear Dwayne Johnson's name, I immediately start mixing it up in weird ways by saying his name and nickname multiple times but in random orders. For example **"Dwayne" "The Rock" "Dwayne" "The Rock" "Johnson" "Johnson"**. But I always follow the same set of rules:

- If I say a number of **"Dwayne"**'s, $n$, I have to say the other two items **"The Rock"** and **"Johnson"** $n$ times as well. Basically the full name needs to be said a whole number of times throughout the expression.
- If I say **"The Rock"** it must be because I said a corresponding **"Dwayne"** sometime before it. For example: **"Dwayne" "The Rock" "The Rock" "Dwayne" "Johnson" "Johnson"** is not valid. The same is the case for the **"Johnson"**'s after **"The Rock"**. i.e. They have to appear in order.

So my question is:

For a given number $n$ of **"Dwayne", "The Rock", and "Johnson"**'s how many different Dwayne The Rock Johnson orderings can I have that follow these rules.

Comment: Are you allowed repetitions? I assume you need/want to use all of the given words. The word n Dwayne's, followed by n The Rock's, followed by n Johnson's, is one valid ordering, but without repetition allowed you have used up all your given words. Removing one of each from this big ordering, gives you a "Dwayne The Rock Johnson" and one word with n-1 Dwayne's, n-1 The Rock's, followed by n-1 Johnson's; so two valid orderings. One can continue in this way. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: if we restrict to just "Dwayne" and "Johnson", this corresponds to the number of [Dyck Paths](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DyckPath.html). Using the full name should be some sort of three-dimensional Dyck path.

Comment: To be clear, I know next to nothing about such things, but I believe this is a question people are essentially interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OEIS: A005789](https://oeis.org/A005789)

> Number of words consisting of n 'x' letters, n 'y' letters and n 'z' letters such that the 'x' count is always greater than or equal to the 'y' count and the 'y' count is always greater than or equal to the 'z' count; e.g., for n=2 we have xxyyzz, xxyzyz, xyxyzz, xyxzyz and xyzxyz.

In this case, 'x' is "Dwayne", 'y' is "The Rock" and 'z' is "Johnson".

Comment: For anyone interested in the name, according to the site, these are called 3 Dimensional Catalan numbers.